Divs with different heights affect the position of others
I need to use the following code:
grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
I need the height of div2 (height: 100px, for example) not to affect the position of div3 (which needs to be in the same position as if there were no height: 100px for div2).
Complete code:


#grid1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

#div1 {
  grid-column: span 8;
}

#div2 {
  grid-column: span 4;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}

#div3 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
<div id='grid1'>

  <div id='div1'>
    <input type='number' style='width: 100%;'>
  </div>

  <div id='div2'>
    <input type='number' style='width: 100%;'>
  </div>

  <div id='div3'>
    <input type='number' style='width: 100%;'>
  </div>

</div>



Again, I need to keep this structure:
grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); with display: grid;.
The solution I'm looking for is some property related to display: grid;, that is, to do this:
#div3 {
  grid-column: span 4;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

Not interesting.
